# Shiny R: Implement Slider Input

Tags: r, shiny

I have this dataset [here](https://ufile.io/0f835) and I would like to create a simple Slider Input where the respective average Temperature of the country will change by changing the year. So far I have written this. I want to project the average Temperature of Canada throughout the years from 1743 till 2013. How should I proceed in making this happen?

**ui.R**

```
fluidPage(
  verticalLayout(
    titlePanel("Russian Average Temperature"),
    plotOutput("plot1"),
    wellPanel(
      sliderInput("Year", "Timeline", 1743, 2013,
                  value = 0, step = 1)
    )
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv("..\\GlobalLandTemperatures\\GlobalLandTemperaturesByState.csv",
                 fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

function(input, output) {

  data  %>%
    filter(Country=="Canada")  %>%
    separate(col = dt, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"), convert = TRUE) ->cCanada
  cCanada<-na.omit(cCanada)

  cCanada %>% 
    filter(Year>1743) %>%
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    summarise(Temp = mean(AverageTemperature)) ->cCanAvgTemp

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(x = Year, y = AverageTemperature)
  })
}
```

Comment: so you would like to display the average Temperature between specific Years thats has been choosen in Your slider?

Comment: Yes something like that. By sliding the slider I would like to demonstrate the specific temperature of that year in the specific country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create reactive dataset, so it will look like that:

```
   data <- reactive({
     if(!is.null(input$Year)){
       data<-cCanAvgTemp %>%
         filter(cCanAvgTemp[ ,Year] >= input$Year[1])
     }
     data
   })

 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(data=data(),x = Year, y = Temp)
  })
```

**[EDIT]** Full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv(".../data.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  verticalLayout(
    titlePanel("Russian Average Temperature"),
    plotOutput("plot1"),
    wellPanel(
      sliderInput("Year", "Timeline", 1743, 2013,
                  value = 0, step = 1)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data  %>%
    filter(Country=="Canada")  %>%
    separate(col = dt, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"), convert = TRUE) ->cCanada
  cCanada<-na.omit(cCanada)

  cCanada %>% 
    filter(Year>1743) %>%
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    summarise(Temp = mean(AverageTemperature)) ->cCanAvgTemp

  data2 <- reactive({
    data <- as.data.frame(cCanAvgTemp)
    if(!is.null(input$Year)){
      data<-data %>%
        filter(data$Year >= input$Year[1]) #to get value for choosen year change >= sign to ==
    }
    data
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data2 <- data2()
    ggplot(data= data2, aes(x = Year, y = Temp)) + geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the edit. But you extract a Year from dt column name exactly in this point: `data  %>%
    filter(Country=="Canada")  %>%
    separate(col = dt, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"), convert = TRUE) ->cCanada`

Comment: Thanks! I would like to specify my question : After I add your code it pops out "Error: object 'Year' not found". What is my mistake in this case ?

Comment: Have You tried the edited version? because when i run it no Error pops out

Comment: Thanks ! I know the concept of the plot is not great... How could I improve it ? Any ideas?

Comment: The concept of the plot makes sense if you wanna display more then one value (and i realised you just want to see the Temp for each Year separately, it means one value). I think the datatable will be sufficient enough or range of the year or one year but many countries..You have endless options actually